# Vector Equation Alignment

Tags: arrays, alignment

I want to write a Bloch equation in beautiful..
this is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial M_x}{\partial t}\\
\dfrac{\partial M_y}{\partial t}\\
\dfrac{\partial M_z}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}=\gamma\begin{pmatrix}
 M_x\\M_y\\M_z
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\B_0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

But i want it to look like this:

[image]

Ty for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX would normally keep the array spacing consistent but you forced it to break its normal rules by using `\dfrac` If you use `\frac` the spacing is consistent, but a little cramped so I added some extra space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial M_x}{\partial t}\\[\jot]
\frac{\partial M_y}{\partial t}\\[\jot]
\frac{\partial M_z}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}=\gamma\begin{pmatrix}
 M_x\\[\jot]M_y\\[\jot]M_z
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
0\\[\jot]0\\[\jot]B_0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a good solution, but is there a way to align such an equation if for example i have a pretty big obejct in 1 vector, and in the other vectors there are normal objects.

Comment: @MarkusHein if you add enough space using `\arraystretch` or `[]` then they will be the same size or you can use `\vphantom{the big object}` in the other arrays to make an invisible rule as high as the big object but zero width that will force the other arrays to be larger or ....

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial M_x}{\partial t}\\
\frac{\partial M_y}{\partial t}\\
\frac{\partial M_z}{\partial t}
\end{pmatrix}=\gamma\begin{pmatrix}
 M_x\\M_y\\M_z
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\B_0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `nccmath` (to obtain medium-sized fractions), `cellspace` (minimal vertical spacing between rows in a table) and `\vphantom`. I added `esdiff` to simplify typing of partial derivatives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\medmath{\begin{pmatrix}
\diffp{M_x}{t}\\
\diffp{M_y}{t}\\
\diffp{M_z}{t}
\end{pmatrix}}=\gamma\begin{pmatrix}
\vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}} M_x\\ \vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}}M_y\\ \vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}}M_z
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
\vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}}0\\ \vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}}0\\ \vphantom{\medmath{\diffp{}{t}}}B_0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]